# ckeditor 4 strips every html tag

Tags: ckeditor, zend-framework2, text-editor

I am using CKEDITOR with my Zend Framework 2 application. When i insert HTML tags and save the form every HTML tag is lost/stripped. Only plain text appears...

I have already tried:

```
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
```

Comment: Have you checked your backend filters? Maybe it's not a CKEditor stripping content.

Comment: I tried the tinymce editor and i have the same problem. so you are right. what do you mean by backend filters?

Comment: yes there was a striptags filter in textarea. thank you very much